# can we add .shp file in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

Actually i need to add **SharpMap** file as a mapView which has extension **.shp** so does any one have any kind of help about how we can use this .shp file as a mapview in ios.

Comment: .shp files are Shapefiles which is an ESRI standard, SharpMap is an opensource .Net project which provides spatial feature and map display using various map formats including Shapefiles. Do you want to Display shapefiles in ios ?

Comment: thanku Habib.OSU sir,yes i want to display shapeFiles in ios and can we use shape file as a map view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.shp files are [Shapefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) which is an [ESRI standard](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) is an opensource .Net project which provides spatial feature and map display using various map formats including Shapefiles.

To read/parse shapefiles and display their geometry in the ios you can try the following: 
[grgcombs / iOS-Shapefile](https://github.com/grgcombs/iOS-Shapefile)

Comment: Habib.OSU, i have three files .shp,.shx,.dbf but on map the area which is in .shp file is not gonna highlight with green color as it is in u r referenced example.

Comment: I too am trying the same  with the project  `iOS-Shapefile`, but no success. I too have three file namely- `world_borders.shp,.dbf,.shp` but not `.cpg & .prj` file . Please help

Comment: `.prj` and `.cpg` files are optional with respect to shapefiles. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: i can able to load the shape file but main issue is map load too slow and when i try to load "road"(roads.cpg,roads.dbf,roads.prj,roads.shp,roads.shx) files app crash.How can i fix this any suggestion or idea @Habib

Comment: @chetu, you can't load all the layers (shape files) together, it will require lots of system resources, instead you need a strategy where you will load Country polygon first, at minimum zoom level, and with every increase in zoom level, load other layers, This will give you a chance to load geometries in a specific and smaller bounding box. Just look how google map works. First it shows the whole world, then country, city, area then roads. This may also require you to generate your own shape files for roads with minimal points (normalized), lesser the points faster the display.